# how to create variables from key value object pair in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
Object {geom: "-116.2, 35.6", hazard_c_5: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223", hazard_c_6: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223", iml: "0.005, 0.007", pga_mean: "0.987965748334, 0.958177134411"
```

How can I create a variable for each key and set its value to the keys respective value?

I was trying this:

```
for(i in data) {
    console.log(i, data[i]);
}
```

But it's not clear to me how to set `i` to a variable and `data.[i]` to the variables value?

I am after:

```
var geom = "-116.2, 35.6";
var hazard_c_5 = "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223";
...
```

**EDIT**

I should also mention that the number of key value pairs in data will change

Comment: Any reason you want to do this? Can't you just access the object properties directly?

Comment: try using :
var Data = Object {geom: "-116.2, 35.6", hazard_c_5: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223", hazard_c_6: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223", iml: "0.005, 0.007", pga_mean: "0.987965748334, 0.958177134411"}
then use
Data.geom
to get the value

Comment: I want to use the values in a D3.js chart, for example the geom value will be used in the chart legend, the hazard & pga values will be used for the x axis and the iml values will be used for the y axis.

Comment: I don't know `d3`. Is there a reason why you can't just use `data.geom` and `data.hazard_c_5` in the code to access the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you want to make global variables, you can just create them as properties in the `window` object:

```
for(i in data) {
  window[i] = data[i];
}
```

Now you can use them just as you would use global variables. The only practical difference between window properties and global variables is that window properties can be deleted.

Comment: I would prefer not to make the variables global if possible, but it worked, thanks

Comment: This is called "Global object pollution", if you're not sure about the name of the properties inside the object you can easily mess all things up, because you could also overwrite other variables of the Window object.

Comment: @Bwyss: The best is of course if you can access the data from your object instead. If you want to create local variables you would need to use the `eval` function, which is doable but not always advisable.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `with` statement, which does exactly that.

```
var data = {
    geom: "-116.2, 35.6",
    hazard_c_5: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223",
    hazard_c_6: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223",
    iml: "0.005, 0.007",
    pga_mean: "0.987965748334, 0.958177134411"
}

with(data) {
    console.log(geom, iml);
}
```

Please note, using `with` stops the JS Engine from making use of several optimizations and there is usually a better way of doing things than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function (context) {
    var data = {
        geom: "-116.2, 35.6",
        hazard_c_5: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223",
        hazard_c_6: "0.970118393901, 0.904556039223",
        iml: "0.005, 0.007",
        pga_mean: "0.987965748334, 0.958177134411"
    };
    for(var i in data) {
         context[i] = data[i];
    };
    alert(geom);
})(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you asked for, but why don't you use the object itself? :/

```
var myObject = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
};

for( i in myObject ) {
    this[i] = myObject[i];
    console.log( this[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why would you EVER do this?**

This is simply wrong.

Of course you can (but shouldn't) use `eval` like `eval("var geom = -116.2, 35.6;") but trust me, you don't need this.

I hope you know that you can access the `geom` value by using `obj.geom`.

But you ask me: Why I shouldn't?

- **Performance**: This will slow down your app. [This](http://hugoware.net/blog/jlinq-reloaded) will show you how much improvements Hugo Bonacci got by simply getting rid of these evals.
- **Security**: An experienced developer could potentially inject code into your application. This can be harmful in several ways.
- **Readabilty and debugging**: Where are these variables coming from? Why creating them using strings? And, what this `eval` function does?

That's it. But you can (shouldn't) use eval. But don't use eval.

Answer (score -1):

edit: before negative voting this answer please **RTFA**, I suggest to **NOT** use evil.

You can do **evil** eval:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    eval("var " + i + " = " + obj[i] + ";");
}
```

but it's a bad bad bad practice, so you should avoid as much as possible. Instead use the property of the object:

```
var geom = obj.geom;
```

but if the problem is that you don't know the properties of an object then you can access them using square brackets:

```
var foo = obj["geom"];
```

where "geom" is a string with the name of the property, i.e.:

```
var key = "geom"
//later in the code
var foo = obj[key]
```